# Should I use nested data structures in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a fairly large database in SQL Server. To illustrate my use case, suppose I have a mobile game and I want to report on user activity.

To start with I have a table that looks like:

| userId | date | # Sessions | Total Session Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 3 | 55 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 9 | 22 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 6 | 43 |

I am trying to "add" information of each session into this data. The options I'm considering are:

1. Add the session data as a new column containing a JSON array with the data for each session
2. Create a table with all session data indexed by `userId` & `date` - and query this table as needed.

Is this possible in SQL Server? (my experience is coming from GCP's BigQuery)

Comment: Either approach is viable depending on what you need to do with this information. If you are going to be querying the data frequently then I would urge you to properly normalize your data into the relevant tables. If you don't you will constantly be parsing your JSON values which is less than ideal. But if it is more historical data then storing it as JSON can be a very reasonable solution. The biggest issue here is there isn't enough information to offer much help. And any advice is going to be opinion based.

Comment: True. In truth I'm trying to build something like a "sparkline" for a few fields - and I'm not sure if a nested JSON is better than multiple queries to get the data. Ie. is it worth minimizing the number of queries to the DB?

Comment: Minimizing queries will come at the cost of normalization, querying complexity, and most importantly performance. A properly normalized database is much more performant. JSON and XML etc are designed for when the structure of values is completely undefined, and you just want to store a blob for the application to retrieve (think documents, PDFs, XHTML, data from very disparate sources)

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to whether it is better to use nested data or to figure out a system of tables where every column of every table has a simple domain  (text string, number, date, etc.).

It turns out that this question was being pondered by Ed Codd fifty years ago when he was proposing the first database system based on the relational model.  He decided that it was worthwhile restricting relational databases to Normal Form, later renamed First Normal Form.  He proved to his own satisfaction that this restriction wouldn't reduce the expressive power of the relational model.   And it would make it easier to build the first relational dabase manager.

Since then, just about every relational or SQL database has conformed to First Normal Form,  although there are ways to get around the restriction by storing one of various forms of data structures in one column of a table.  JSON is an example.

You'll gain the flexibility you get with JSON,  but you will lose the ability to specify the data you want to retrieve using the various clauses of the SELECT statement, clauses like INNER JOIN or WHERE, among others. This loss could be deal killer.

If it were me,  I would go with the added table approach, and analyze the session data down to one of more tables with simple columns.  But you may find that JSON decoders are just as powerful, and that doing full table scans are worth the time taken.